# Why was this application using SKPSMTPMessage rejected?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I developed one app for to send e-mails with the apple account of the users. For this the app use the SKPSMTPMessage open source.

I was waiting for the validation of my application in iTunes Connect and at the end they told me that:

- The application asks for the users Apple email and password. The app should be able to accept all emails and passwords.

With SKPSMTPMessage frameWork you must defined the e-mail server to use and I don't know another alternative.

What can I do to work around this rejection?

Answer (score 0):

If you modify your app to accept the SMTP server, email address, server username and password as user input (like most other general email apps do) and you should be fine, no?

Comment: Ok.. If I understand you say that the app has to ask the SMTP server too... Yes is one option, but I don't like this, do you think that this is the only way?